# copy range but hide shapes inside

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

Is it possible to copy range in Excel by VBA but with shapes inside of it, hidden?
I tried to hide shapes, select range, and then to show them again but selection 'stays open' so to speak, until it is pasted, so shapes appears. Is it possible to put it in clipboard immediately , before they are shown again? 
this is what i tried:

```
Sub copyIt()
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Shape.Visible = msoFalse
    Next

    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Copy

    For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Shape.Visible = msoTrue
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid putting any code between the *copy* and the *paste*.  Say we start with:

[image]

We will:

- hide the shape
- perform copy/paste
- verify the shapes are hidden
- un-hide the shapes
- verify the shape was copied along with the cells

  Sub Shapee()
      Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
      Dim Sh As Shape
      Set r1 = Range("A1:F14")
      Set r2 = Range("H1")

  ```
  For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
      Sh.Visible = msoFalse
  Next

  r1.Copy r2
  MsgBox "INSPECT SHEET"

  For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
      Sh.Visible = msoTrue
  Next
  MsgBox "INSPECT SHEET AGAIN"
  ```

  End Sub

Comment: Thanks for answer. Maybe I wasn't clear. Pasting are done in another application, in AutoCad to be precise, so i would like to get my range selected and copied and ready for pasting without extra step of confirming popup message. It would be nice if in step:  'ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Copy'  i could get it somehow in clipboard...